# Ajax textfield in hook_form_alter

Tags: 8, forms

I'm attaching ajax on textfield value. One enter value in textfield and ajax callback returns form element.

Below code is showing ajax 500 error. Can anyone tell what is mistake in this code?

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    $form['field_base_price']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'final-price-wrapper',
            'callback' => 'final_price_ajax_callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
          );

    $form['field_final_price']['#prefix'] = '<div id="final-price-wrapper">';
        $form['field_final_price']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
          $form['final_price_label'] = array(
            '#weight' => 11,
            '#prefix' => '<div id="final-price-wrapper" class="field-name-field-final-price form-item">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
          );
          $form['final_price_label']['title'] = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<label>' . $form['field_final_price']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] . '</label>',
          );

    }

    /**
     * Final price AJAX callback.
     */
    function final_price_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
      return $form['final_price_label'];
    }
```

[image]

Comment: A 500 error can mean anything, could be a missing ";". You need a full error message, so that you know where to look.

Comment: Do you have access to the apache or nginx error log? As 4k4 mentioned, more detail is needed to provide the proper feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple jQuery to achieve this then. Try putting the following code in your JS file:

```
$("#fname").blur(function(){
  var fname = $("#fname").val();
$("#lname").val(fname);
});
```

Comment: but on saving my node, this value not saved in db, we have to go with the ajax approach because jquery is client side.

Comment: You can get the data of field on the controller.php file and then assign the data to some variable. Then assign that variable to the column variable in the DB. Insert the values in the DB. Done.